# Replace value of datetime from a file

Tags: python, datetime

I would like to calculate the delta from 2 date.

I have in a .txt this:

```
2020,12,10,07,00,00
```

Then in the script:

```
import time
from time import strftime
import datetime
from datetime import date

var1 = datetime.datetime(2012,12,31,24,60,60)

Current_Time = datetime.datetime(int(time.strftime("%Y")), int(time.strftime("%m")), int(time.strftime("%d")), int(time.strftime("%H")), int(time.strftime("%M")),  int(time.strftime("%S")) )

var3 = Current_Time - var1

print var3
```

I know that I need to import the file:

```
    fichier = open("datescenario.txt", 'rt')
    datefichier = fichier.read()
```

But how to replace the value of var1 from the content of the .txt ?
If needed I can change the value from the .txt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**You can try to do it like this:**
Open the file and split the line in the file by "," store the split line in a list then select each value with its index from the list.

```
# opening the file
fichier = open("datescenario.txt", "r" )
datefichier = fichier.read()

# splitting the string 5 times by "," symbol
lst = date_f.split(",",5) 

# picking values from list with their index
year = int(lst[0])
month = int(lst[1])
day = int(lst[2])
hour = int(lst[3])
minute = int(lst[4])
second = int(lst[5])

# using variables instead of integers in datetime()
var1 = datetime.datetime(year, month, day, hour, minute, second)

# don't forget to close the file too
fichier.close()
```

Comment: As a slight improvement, you could directly use lst: `var1 = datetime.datetime(*lst)`

Comment: Will that work if the list elements are strings?